# Sides to the argument?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, exceptions

Is it correct to say "There are two sides to the argument"? I know "two sides *of* the argument" is definitely grammatically correct, but the former also feels right and has a different emphasis. And if it is correct, what makes it so?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't correct?

Answer (score 1):

They're literally identical in meaning, but using *to*, as you suggested, is more idiomatic (no clue why). As far as grammar goes, both *to* and *of* denote possession (i.e. The argument "possesses" two sides).

Sidenote:
The only more detailed answer I could give you would be making use of Latin grammar rules (which can often be applied well to English): *of* is how one would translate the use of the *genitive* case of a noun - the traditional form used to express possession - whereas *to* is how one would translate the use of the *dative* noun case, sometimes used in constructions called "datives of possession," which are alternative methods of achieving the same possessive meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with Nick that they are literally identical in meaning (though I agree that they are in practice synonymous).

To me, they have a different structure:

> 1)  There are two [sides of the argument].

vs

> 2) There are [two sides] [to the argument].

My reason for saying this is that I don't find * *a side to the argument* to be idiomatic, so 2) cannot have the structure of 1).